# Strange issue with the back button going back two pages

Tags: back-button-control

Here is the link to my full project in github:
[my project code](https://github.com/swaffleman/project)

Anyway, It all works exactly as I want it to, but with one weird little glitch: when on the photos page, and you click on a photo to view it, and then click back, it goes back two pages instead of one. I don't have the slightest idea how to stop it from doing this.

The photos view is in public/views.

Thanks.

-Steve

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you updated your question with a one or a few code snippets that you think might be related to the problem. Please also include information such as plugins used, etc.

Comment: Thanks for already commenting but I have circumvented the problem by just making it so that if you click on each picture, it loads it into a new tab. Is there a way to ask for this to be closed?